# Decode in Python

Tags: python, decode, encode, translate, binascii

I am trying to discover text encoded in ASCII found within a DNA sequence from a file.

Below is my code:

The first is to open the FASTA file and set is a variable.

```
with open("/home/<username>/python/progseq") as mydnaseq:
    sequence = mydnaseq.read().replace('\n','')
```

This second bit is to translate the sequence into binary and did this for the letters C and G/T to equal 1:

```
binarysequence = sequence.replace('A','0')
```

Then I took this loooooong binary sequence and wanted to make it into 8bits:

```
for i in range(0,len(binarysequence),8):
    binarysequence [i:i+8]
```

This then created an output like this:

```
    '00110100'
    '00110010'
    '01000110'
    '00011000'
    '0'
```

Though I had a much longer output I only included the last four of the sequence.

Wanted to know how to convert this into letters.

Comment: You can convert an ASCII string into a binary (bytes) with `sequence.encode()`. The function replaces every character with its 8-bit ASCII charcode. E.g., 'A' becomes 65. But what do you plan to do next with these bits?

Comment: Hello @DYZ, thanks for replying. I wanted to replace these series of 8 bits (not just these four) with the respective ASCII character as I am told it is suppose to reveal a poem.  I just don't know how yet and was wondering whether to use encode() or decode() or if there was a different way of approaching. I hope I am making sense. I am new to the programming world.

Comment: I shouldn't have used ord() but translate each letter ([A,C=0][T,G=1]) accordingly. I'm just unsure where to start with this now.

Answer (score 0):

With e.g. `a = '10010000'`, you can do

```
b = chr(int(a, 2))
```

to first convert `a` into an integer based on the binary number and then interpret this integer as a character. Note that many of these 8-bit integers will not result in readable characters!

A concrete example is

```
b = chr(int('01111000', 2))
print(b)
```

which result in `'x'` being printed.

Comment: Thanks so much for replying.
I tried doing b = chr(int(binarysequence,2)) but Python told me it was too large.
I'm trying to avoid manually inputting each byte as I have too many and I'm sure there's a simpler way. I'm just unsure what it is yet.
Thanks again.

Comment: What do you mean *manually*? Why not just use `chr(int(binarysequence[i:i+8], 2))` in your loop and maybe append the result to a list as you go?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It really helped! :)

Comment: I think I've stumbled upon another issue. It wasn't the output I expected (supposed to be a poem) but it did give me a few letters so I'm thinking of maybe needing to use binascii? but still reading into it.